# Controlling commit/rollback in spring batch using JdbcBatchItemWriter

Tags: java, database, transactions, spring-batch, commit

I am using spring batch to read data form database and write it to file.
Following are the steps involved:
1. Read data from database
2. Write data to file
3. Update database rows if file write is successful.

According to spring batch documentation and other sources, I can use JdbcBatchItemWriter for updating database entries. But I could not find any mechanism to control commit/rollback while updating the rows.
Say there are 100 rows and an error occurs at 45th row, I need to rollback all the updates.
Is there some way in JdbcBatchItemWriter to explicitly commit or rollback the transaction?

**EDIT**
The Itemwriter will data to file in chunks. Once a chunk is written, I need to update records in database. The database update is done using JdbcBatchItemWriter. Say 5 chunks are written successfully, and chunk 6 throws error in 45th record, I need to rollback all the chunks. Therefore I need commit/rollback control in JdbcBatchItemWriter.

Answer (score 0):

commit/rollback or transactional behaviour in general is provided and controlled by the framework, the same applies to fault tolerant steps using skip

> Say there are 100 rows and an error occurs at 45th row, I need to rollback all the updates.
>   Is there some way in JdbcBatchItemWriter to explicitly commit or rollback the transaction?

that behaviour is provided automatically by spring batch, it will be rollbacked and - by using skip logic - the other 99 rows will be processed and committed

[Chunkoriented processing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#chunkOrientedProcessing) :

> Chunk oriented processing refers to reading the data one at a time,
>   and creating 'chunks' that will be written out, within a transaction
>   boundary. One item is read in from an ItemReader, handed to an
>   ItemProcessor, and aggregated. Once the number of items read equals
>   the commit interval, the entire chunk is written out via the
>   ItemWriter, and then the transaction is committed.

see also:

- [CommitInterval](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#commitInterval)
- [skip logic](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#configuringSkip)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael. But I am not referring to chunk processing here. I have written a custom ItemWriter which writes data to a file. That processing will be handled in chunk. But once the data is written to file, I want to update the records in database. That is where I use JdbcBatchItemWriter. I have written whole logic myself. The Itemwriter will write data to file in chunks. Say 5 chunks are written successfully and chunk 6 throws error in 45th record. In that case I need to rollback entire 6 chunks. That is why I need commit/rollback control in JdbcBatchItemWriter.

Comment: well without nested transactions you probably can't rollback the (already committed) 6 chunks, i would try it with a "RollbackStep" and some marker in database to be able to just delete the inserted records

Answer (score 0):

There is no way within Spring Batch by default to roll back a committed transaction.  What you'll need to do is add compensating logic in another step that would be called if the step in question failed.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks